# Referential Integrity in Purview from SQL tables

Tags: sql-server, azure-purview

I am trying to see if Purview can get referential integrity information from SQL tables. I am not finding any documentation on how it can be done. Can someone please help!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Per Microsoft support

> there is a feature implementation in the roadmap for later this year, but we don’t have specific ETA at this point.

See link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/753322/azure-sql-database39s-primary-key-and-foreign-key.html)

So as of now Purview can not figure out PK FK from MS SQL server databases

Comment: Thank you DhruvJoshi. Appreciate your response.